# AngularFire's $loaded/$watch not being triggered in Ionic application

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, angularfire, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing an Ionic application for the Android platform and I've ran into the following problem using Angularfire's $loaded/$watch function.

The controller uses AngularFire's $firebaseObject to retrieve student information, and then uses the $loaded function to print a message once the data is retrieved. Similarly, it uses a $watch to print a message when the data changes.

The problem is that sometimes these messages do not get printed to the console when the view is visited. Let's say neither of the messages get printed, by navigating to another controller, they get printed to the console.

Sometimes, the $loaded message will be printed, but the $watch will not be triggered when changes are made in Firebase, until we navigate away to a different controller.

Sometimes, they both work perfectly.

Once thing I've noticed is that by force stopping the application and restarting it, the application behaves as intended.

```
var firebaseDatabase = FirebaseService.getFirebaseDatabase();

var student = $firebaseObject(firebaseDatabase.ref('randomstudentid/'));

student.$loaded().then(function(){
  console.log("The student information has been loaded.");
});

student.$watch(function(){
  console.log("A watch has been triggered on the student information.");
});
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29127168/scope-watch-in-angular-doesnt-work-in-ionic-cordova